# Issue using kafka-topics cli command with TLS enabled

Tags: java, ssl, apache-kafka

I'm using Using latest landoop/fast-data-dev image (but the Kafka cli tools are the same as upstream)

When trying this command within the container:

```
root@fast-data-dev / $ ./opt/landoop/kafka/bin/kafka-topics --bootstrap-server hostname:9093 --command-config client.properties -list
```

I get this error

```
[2020-11-26 18:09:01,580] WARN The configuration 'ssl.truststore.location' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig) 
[2020-11-26 18:09:01,581] WARN The configuration 'ssl.keystore.password' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig) 
[2020-11-26 18:09:01,582] WARN The configuration 'ssl.keystore.location' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig) 
[2020-11-26 18:09:01,582] WARN The configuration 'ssl.truststore.password' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
```

Here is my client.properties file

```
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/data/cluster-crt/ca.p12
ssl.truststore.password=valid_password
ssl.keystore.location=/data/user-crt/user.p12
ssl.keystore.password=valid_pasword
```

Am I doing something wrong ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's related to this known issue, but the admin client should work anyway.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-10566

There is also a PR opened to fix it.

https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/9365